# 'ColorField' object has no attribute 'model' django

Tags: python, django

I am using ColorField that I found on the internet, and it is working alright when I set the color from admin site, but when I create my own form I get this error:

```
'ColorField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

It says "Error during template rendering", and showing that the error is in this line:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label class="control-label" for="formGroupInputLarge">Color: </label>
    {{ form.color }}
</div>
```

This is my models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank = False, max_length = 100)
    beggining_time= models.DateTimeField(blank = True)
    ending_time = models.DateTimeField(blank = True)
    color = ColorField(default='#FF0000')
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
```

This is my views.py file:

```
def calendar(request, pYear, pMonth, id):
    """
    Show calendar of events for specified month and year
    """
    lYear = int(pYear)
    lMonth = int(pMonth)
    lContestEvents = Smena.objects.filter(manager= Manager.objects.filter(user= User.objects.filter(id = id)))
    lCalendar = WorkoutCalendar(lContestEvents).formatmonth(lYear, lMonth)
    lPreviousYear = lYear
    lPreviousMonth = lMonth - 1
    if lPreviousMonth == 0:
        lPreviousMonth = 12
        lPreviousYear = lYear - 1
    lNextYear = lYear
    lNextMonth = lMonth + 1
    if lNextMonth == 13:
        lNextMonth = 1
        lNextYear = lYear + 1
    lYearAfterThis = lYear + 1
    lYearBeforeThis = lYear - 1

    form = AddEvent(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.manager= Manager.objects.filter(user= User.objects.filter(id = id))
        instance.save()

    return render(request, 'template.html', {'Calendar' : mark_safe(lCalendar),
                                                       'Month' : lMonth,
                                                       'MonthName' : named_month(lMonth),
                                                       'Year' : lYear,
                                                       'PreviousMonth' : lPreviousMonth,
                                                       'PreviousMonthName' : named_month(lPreviousMonth),
                                                       'PreviousYear' : lPreviousYear,
                                                       'NextMonth' : lNextMonth,
                                                       'NextMonthName' : named_month(lNextMonth),
                                                       'NextYear' : lNextYear,
                                                       'YearBeforeThis' : lYearBeforeThis,
                                                       'YearAfterThis' : lYearAfterThis,
                                                       'form' : form,
                                                   })
```

This is my forms.py file:

```
class AddEvent(forms.Form):

    name= forms.CharField()
    beggining_time= forms.DateTimeField()
    ending_time= forms.DateTimeField()
    color = ColorField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'beggining_time', 'ending_time', 'color']
```

As I said, I can add events from admin page, but I cannot display the form on my website. I get the mentioned error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the `ColorField` coming from? There's no such thing in django.

Comment: Found it here:     https://github.com/jaredly/django-colorfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the **model** `ColorField` in your **form**, but those are two completely different contexts. It also looks like you're trying to use a regular form as a `ModelForm`.

[Introduction to `ModelForm`s](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/).

Change your form to look like this:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name', 'beggining_time', 'ending_time', 'color']
```

This will automatically use the `ColorWidget` **form** field widget when rendering.

Comment: Yes it works, but the field is not displayed like it is on the admin page... On admin page I can choose color which I want, and now I can only enter manualy color that i want, for example #ff0000, and I cant see whic color that is

Comment: It should be using the same widget as the admin. Might be an issue of the javascript not loading. First check if [this template](https://github.com/jaredly/django-colorfield/blob/master/colorfield/templates/colorfield/color.html) is used in the page. If it is, debug the static files (need to have `jscolor.js` load).

Comment: Tank you, it worked. I just loaded jscolor.js file and it works fine.